# Date validator checking format 'Y-m' failing for month 02 (February)?

Tags: php, validation, datetime, datetime-format

From top comment under the [function reference for `checkdate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) in the PHP manual, I grabbed the code for a date & time validator and modified it for my use like so:

```php
function so_validate_date( $date, $format ) {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, $date );
    return $d && $d->format( $format ) == $date;
}
```

The logic makes sense to me but something's wrong with it because it fails to validate dates of format `Y-m` when the month is `02` (February).

For e.g.

```php
function test_validate_date( $date = '2011-02', $format = 'Y-m' ) {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, $date );
    echo $d->format( $format ); // outputs 2011-03, NOT 2011-02!
}
```

The output of `test_validate_date()` which I expect to be `2011-02` is, surprisingly, `2011-03`. I have no idea why.

What am I missing here? Appreciate any help fixing the logic (or whatever I got wrong here).

Comment: Today is the 29th, there are 28 days in feb 2011.  When combined with this note from your manual page “If format does not contain the character ! then portions of the generated time which are not specified in format will be set to the current system time.“. Could it be taking today’s date and overflowing the month to March?  Try processing the input date with a `!` in the format string

Comment: @James You are right. I just came across this comment after posting the question: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#110385

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that when you use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat) and you don't specify parts of the date, PHP substitutes the current value of that field:

> If format does not contain the character ! then portions of the generated time which are not specified in format will be set to the current system time.

So, given that today is December 30th (possibly the 29th where you are), you are trying to create the date `2011-02-30` which PHP conveniently converts to `2011-03-02` which then outputs as `2011-03` in `Y-m` format.

To work around this, specify a `!` at the beginning of the format string so that

> portions of the generated time not provided in format, as well as values to the left-hand side of the !, will be set to corresponding values from the Unix epoch (`1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`).

```
function so_validate_date( $date, $format ) {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat( "!$format", $date );
    return $d && $d->format( $format ) == $date;
}

echo so_validate_date('2011-02', 'Y-m') ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Output:

```
true
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2GTKO)

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Although not the solution, I came across this comment after posting the question: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#110385 (Made it clear where I was going wrong.) Again, thank you very much!